# Collapsing columns and removing NAs

Tags: r, tidyr

I have a data.frame, in this format:

```
A   w   x   y   z
0.23    1   NA  NA  NA
0.12    NA  2   NA  NA
0.45    NA  2   NA  NA
0.89    NA  NA  3   NA
0.12    NA  NA  NA  4
```

And I want to collapse w:x:y:z into a single column, while removing NA's. Desired result:

```
A   Comb
0.23    1
0.12    2
0.45    2
0.89    3
0.12    4
```

My approach so far is:

```
df %>% unite("Comb", w:x:y:z, na.rm=TRUE, remove=TRUE)
```

However, "Comb" is being populated with strings such as `1_NA_NA_NA` and `NA_NA_NA_4` i.e. it is not removing the NA's. I've tried switching to character NA's, but that leads to bizarre and unpredictable results. What am I doing wrong?

I'd also like to be able to do this when the original data.frame is populated with strings (in place of the numbers). Is there a method for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `dplyr::coalesce` we can do the following:

```
df %>%
mutate(Comb = coalesce(w,x,y,z)) %>%
  select(A, Comb)
```

which gives the following output:

```
      A  Comb
  <dbl> <dbl>
1  0.23     1
2  0.12     2
3  0.45     2
4  0.89     3
5  0.12     4
```

Answer (score 1):

In `unite`, `na.rm` does not remove integer/factor columns.

Convert them to the character and then use `unite`.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate_at(vars(w:z), as.character) %>% 
  tidyr::unite('comb', w:z, na.rm = TRUE)

#     A comb
#1 0.23    1
#2 0.12    2
#3 0.45    2
#4 0.89    3
#5 0.12    4
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(A = c(0.23, 0.12, 0.45, 0.89, 0.12), w = c(1L, 
NA, NA, NA, NA), x = c(NA, 2L, 2L, NA, NA), y = c(NA, NA, NA, 
3L, NA), z = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 4L)), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is `fcoalesce` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[,  .(A, Comb = fcoalesce(w, x, y, z))]
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(A = c(0.23, 0.12, 0.45, 0.89, 0.12), w = c(1L, 
NA, NA, NA, NA), x = c(NA, 2L, 2L, NA, NA), y = c(NA, NA, NA, 
3L, NA), z = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 4L)), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `na.omit`.

```
dat <- transform(dat[1], Comb=apply(dat[-1], 1, na.omit))
#      A Comb
# 1 0.23    1
# 2 0.12    2
# 3 0.45    2
# 4 0.89    3
# 5 0.12    4
```

---

*Data*

```
dat <- structure(list(A = c(0.23, 0.12, 0.45, 0.89, 0.12), w = c(1L, 
NA, NA, NA, NA), x = c(NA, 2L, 2L, NA, NA), y = c(NA, NA, NA, 
3L, NA), z = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 4L)), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")
```